# Cubic interpolation in Pandas raises ValueError: The number of derivatives at boundaries does not match: expected 2, got 0+0

Tags: python, pandas

I am getting the following error

```
ValueError: The number of derivatives at boundaries does not match: expected 2, got 0+0
```

while trying to use cubic interpolation in pandas on a 2d matrix.

```
mat = pd.read_csv("m.csv")
mat = mat.interpolate(method='cubic')
```

Csv to reproduce can be downloaded [here](http://www.sharecsv.com/s/dca35c0a2ae263237dc303e7358397da/m.csv)

Answer (score 4):

I think the issue is that you need at least 4 points for cubic interpolation, look at this : [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57412489/pandas-interpolate-returning-valueerrors-for-some-methods-and-some-sizes-of-data). It works for column 0:

```py
    mat['0'].interpolate(method='cubic', inplace=True)
    print(mat)

           0         1         2         3         4         5         6         7         8         9        10        11        12  13
0  -0.000347       NaN  0.002546       NaN  0.001891       NaN       NaN       NaN  0.001845       NaN  0.001507       NaN  0.000452 NaN
1   0.000210       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  0.002109       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN NaN
2   0.000438       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  0.004112       NaN       NaN NaN
3   0.000419       NaN       NaN  0.001114       NaN  0.000599  0.003813       NaN  0.003342       NaN       NaN       NaN  0.001095 NaN
4   0.000240  0.001143       NaN  0.002955       NaN  0.004867  0.000857       NaN  0.002584       NaN       NaN  0.002765 -0.000012 NaN
5  -0.000016       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN NaN
6  -0.000264       NaN       NaN -0.000257       NaN  0.002049  0.001710       NaN -0.000041       NaN       NaN       NaN  0.000934 NaN
7  -0.000419  0.003044       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  0.001225       NaN       NaN NaN
8  -0.000397       NaN  0.001417       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  0.001647       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN NaN
9  -0.000169       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  0.000154       NaN       NaN       NaN  0.000424 -0.000507       NaN  0.000550 NaN
10  0.000072       NaN       NaN  0.000768       NaN       NaN  0.000315       NaN       NaN  0.000055 -0.000477       NaN  0.002413 NaN
11  0.000078       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  0.000512       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN NaN
12 -0.000399       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  0.003461  0.001000       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  0.001112 NaN
13 -0.001608       NaN  0.001928       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  0.001780  0.002132       NaN       NaN NaN
```